# How to set PR_HTML where string contains Unicode characters

Tags: outlook, vsto, mapi

In a VSTO C# Outlook addin I am copying the OOM `HTMLBody` text from one message and then adding it to a new message via PR_HTML with either [IMAPIProp::SetProps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/imapiprop-setprops) or [IMAPIProp::OpenProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/imapiprop-openproperty). **I need to take the OOM HTMLBody**.

The issue I am having is that german characters such as äüß are not being set properly on the resulting message.

First I am converting the HTML string to a Byte array with `byte[] bytes= System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);`

Then for example i use OpenProperty

```
OpenProperty((uint)PropTags.PR_HTML, Storage.IID_Stream, (uint)(STGM.CREATE | STGM.WRITE), OpenPropertyMode.MODIFY | OpenPropertyMode.CREATE, out IntPtr pObject);
if (pObject != null && pObject != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    Ole.IStream htmlStream = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(pObject) as Ole.IStream;
    Storage.Write(htmlStream, bytes);
    htmlStream.Commit((int)STGC.DEFAULT);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(htmlStream);
}
```

My IMAPIProp::OpenProperty looks like this:

```
OpenProperty(uint ulPropTag, ref Guid lpiid, uint ulInterfaceOptions, uint ulFlags, out IntPtr lppUnk);
```

Alternative if possible I could try (normally try this first) to set the property with SetProps. Here I think is the bits that are critical.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct pSPropValue
{
    public UInt32 ulPropTag;
    public UInt32 dwAlignPad;
    public _PV Value;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
internal struct _PV
{
    //there are others just showing the one used.
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public SBinary bin;
    
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct SBinary
{
    public uint cb;
    public IntPtr lpb;
}


public static SBinary SBinaryCreate(byte[] data)
{
    SBinary b;
    b.cb = (uint)data.Length;
    b.lpb = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)b.cb);
    for (int i = 0; i < b.cb; i++)
        Marshal.WriteByte(b.lpb, i, data[i]);
    return b;
}

pSPropValue val = new pSPropValue();
//add the property tag
//call SBinaryCreate to create the _PV
val.Value.bin = SBinary.SBinaryCreate(prop.AsBinary);
```

I believe this is all the critical encoding parts. An array of pSPropValue is marshalled to a IntPtr and then SetProps is called.

The resulting email body does not show the special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you correctly set `PR_INTERNET_CHARSET`  property. But most importantly, do not store any non-ASCII characters in HTML. They must be properly HTML-encoded.

Comment: Problem is non-ASCII characters in HTML, the HTMLBody shows them all in the string representation. I tested it with a simple Replace("Ä", "&Auml;"); and it is displaying properly but using WebUtility.HtmlEncode shows the raw html as a result in the message n Outlook.

Comment: Are you saying you have no control over the HTMLBody property and what's in it? If you are copying from another message, why not retrieve `PR_HTML` in a similar manner instead of converting a Unicode string to single byte always assuming UTF-8 (which is not true in most cases)?

Comment: Reason I’m using OOM HTMLbody is if the email is a rpmsg type the MAPIOBJECT (unlike for encrypted) is no help. OOM RTFBody throws an exception checking for null and the property accessor give mixed results.

Comment: Try to avoid assuming UTF-8 encoding. Firstly, looks at the charset header in HTML. If it is missing, use PR_INTERNET_CPID

Comment: Thank you, OOM HTMLbody has no charset and the source message (using MAPI) has a PR_INTERNET_CPID of 1252 which is because the actual message is some simple microsoft text (real message is in the attachment). Encoding with 65001 and setting it as the PR_INTERNET_CPID fixes the issue for this message but what can I do more generally? Do I need to use some detection code on the HTML string to work out its codepage number?

Comment: Yes, if I remember my experiments long time ago correctly, Outlook looks for the charset header in HTML, and, if it is missing, uses PR_INTERNET_CPID